# How do you read excel files using Spout as efficiently as website says?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Due to time-outs using PHPExcel, I am experimenting with Spout.

I understood it differs from PHPExcel in that it reads a row at a time. I tried a file with 116,652 rows (and about 21MB) inserting logging at specific points within the code to track how long things are taking.

To my surprise this statement (right after instantiating $reader with ReaderFactory class):

```
$reader->open($inputFileName);
```

took 30 minutes to execute.

Is there some setting I'm missing out? I've done nothing different from what is instructed [here](http://opensource.box.com/spout/getting-started/).

Answer (score 0):

30 minutes for 116,000 rows is definitely not normal. The `open` function may take a while when using `sharedStrings` (as opposed to `inlineStrings`). Excel is using shared strings by default (which optimizes the size of the XLSX file) while Spout uses inline strings by default (which optimizes for future read performance).

To understand what could go wrong, let me explain what's done in the `open` function:

An XLSX file is a bunch of XML files zipped together. Each XML file contains specific data describing the spreadsheet. There is one XML file describing the structure of the spreadsheet (row1 > cell A1 > A1 value - cell B1 > B1 value -- row2 > cell A2 > A2 value, ...).

The value of the cells can either be inline, so directly present in this file or in the case of strings, these values may contain references only. So for instance, the value for A1 is the string with reference 1, the value for A2 is the string of reference 3, etc. This is useful for space optimization, as a repeated value will only be stored once. Only its reference will be duplicated. That's how the shared strings work.

So when Spout reads an XLXS file that uses shared strings, it needs to know which string correspond to the reference 1 or 3. For that, it first needs to read the file containing all these strings and store the mapping somewhere (string 1 = "foo", string 3 = "bar") so that when it reads the file containing the structure of the spreadsheet, it can translate "string with reference 1" into "foo".

If the file containing the shared strings is very big, Spout does not try to keep the mapping "string reference" => "actual value" in memory but splits this file in smaller chunks. This whole process (reading + splitting) takes a while hence the long wait during the `open` execution.

Now, unless you have a very large number of cells, it should not take 30 minutes.
The most likely reason is that your spreadsheet contains more than one sheet (they may be hidden, but Spout still processes all the strings).

So check that, and if that's not the reason, please [create an issue on Github](https://github.com/box/spout/issues/new), attaching the file you have problems with.